# How to pass data fetched from graphql API to React class component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

according to gatsby documentation we can pass data featched as data parameter to functional component (source : https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-gatsby-source-graphql/src/pages/index.js), how can i pass this data to a class component

```
    import React from "react"
    import Layout from "../../components/layout"
    import { Row, Col, Button, Form, Pagination } from "react-bootstrap"
    import { Link } from "gatsby"
    import { Subscribe } from "../../components/stories/subscribe"

   export default class Home extends React.Component {
      state = {
      }


      render(data) {
        return (
          <Layout>
            <Subscribe />
            <Form>
              <Row>IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII</Row>
              <Row>{JSON.stringify(data)}</Row>
              <Row>IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIoooIIIIIIIIIIIII</Row>
              <Row></Row>
              </div>
            ))}
            <Row>
              <Pagination>
                <Pagination.Prev> Prev</Pagination.Prev>
              </Pagination>
              <Col xs={8}></Col>
              <Pagination>
                <Pagination.Next> Next</Pagination.Next>
              </Pagination>
            </Row>
          </Layout>
        )
      }
    }

    export const query = graphql`
      query {
        api {
          publicfeed {
            total
            posts {
              id
              content
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
```

Comment: `this.props.data` ?

Answer (score 1):

The data for a page Query is available in props and not as an argument to render. You can access it like this.props.data

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
      state = {
      }


      render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        return (
          <Layout>
            <Subscribe />
            <Form>
              <Row>IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII</Row>
              <Row>{JSON.stringify(data)}</Row>
              <Row>IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIoooIIIIIIIIIIIII</Row>
              <Row></Row>
              </div>
            ))}
            <Row>
              <Pagination>
                <Pagination.Prev> Prev</Pagination.Prev>
              </Pagination>
              <Col xs={8}></Col>
              <Pagination>
                <Pagination.Next> Next</Pagination.Next>
              </Pagination>
            </Row>
          </Layout>
        )
      }
    }
```